# How to add an IP address to NAT table (Linux Debian) - POSTROUTING chain

Tags: linux, routes, firewall, iptables, nat

I would need to add an IP address to na NAT table in Linux Debian, with accept policy. I have no idea how to NAT an IP address...

Comment: Can you post your current nat table entries? Easiest way is with `iptables-save -t nat`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what type of OS you're using, but most of the times a linux distro is shipped with firewall iptables. When you Google on iptables and accept ip-address you get a lot of hits. I think this link will solve your issue: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Comment: Its Linux Debian. I have searched, but when i add an IP to iptables, it still doesnt allow the traffic. I believe that i must add it in POSTROUTING chain, but i dont know how.

Comment: Pure Debian or is there a shell over Debian e.g. Ubuntu, RaspBMC? For example, I used RaspBMC on my Raspberry Pi and can also not open my ports. Maybe you have the same. See the last comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5334/how-can-i-disable-raspbmcs-firewall-via-ssh

Comment: Pure Debian 7 (Wheezy)

Comment: Then follow the Debian documentation of iptables: https://wiki.debian.org/iptables